# Android sending data through USB

Tags: java, android, usb

I need to create an application where a tablet will be connected to USB. The tablet will then connect to SQL Server 2008 to update data. As far as I understand, the data will be taken in the tablet, saved in the tablet (I assume I will be using SQLite to save the data) and when the tablet is connected to a computer in the network, it will update the database in SQL Server with the new data it has that is not yet available in the SQL Server tables. I did, of course, consider doing a Web Service, since this is the easiest way to do it. But the company doesn't want to register the tablets in the network so sending data through wireless will not be possible.

My question is, does anyone have any idea how can I use the USB connectivity in my application? I have searched and searched and found no way to do it. I saw something about the ADK but I don't think that is what I'm looking for. I just want to transfer data from the Android tablet through USB. I'll probably have to do some sort of Java application that can read the data sent through USB and then INSERT it to SQL Server.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.